# can you explain this type of error while uploading an image in python "An error occurred while loading the image"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

so I am typing a command as "code costume1.gif" in terminal in vs code python to upload a cat animation but facing an error as "An error occurred while loading the image"
Is this is the problem of any extension file or other?

Comment: What does this have to do with Python? This is a question about using VS Code.

Comment: I think the problem is that it's not a valid GIF file. Can you view it in a browser or image viewer?

Comment: `upload an animation`: where do you want to upload to, VSC is an editor